# Any way to block DNS response using BIND?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, attacks

I am using BIND as my DNS-server. I have disabled recursive DNS-request. Now I am under some kind of attack. Is there any was to block this or do I have to let it go?

My query log:

```
client 75.214.6.32#39884: query: elipylavofkb.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 19.61.194.206#59208: query: mzynovatmhapahen.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 108.8.241.1#50963: query: mdelolwtspupyzmz.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 112.224.24.10#63434: query: wdybkhodehov.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 76.160.109.141#1231: query: gxefmpidgjur.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 16.18.114.118#37018: query: engjcvwjsdgz.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 114.99.158.44#33012: query: ulkhwvopolud.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 50.171.130.116#58826: query: uneburexorkbsrgx.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 96.17.162.81#24693: query: unsjwpinczcd.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 116.158.62.221#9755: query: clylslwdwlov.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 114.197.183.246#39810: query: qjyn.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 82.43.231.89#35249: query: yxwlubah.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 21.189.79.22#30864: query: wpgboted.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 50.107.178.249#5585: query: kzwhmdqjqrat.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 14.57.75.38#26008: query: ojudkzytqlqn.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 98.214.7.43#51927: query: md.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 61.51.158.42#5778: query: ufstavonszktox.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 24.221.104.57#38899: query: gpexcvixodaj.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 75.217.45.169#50011: query: ybmdyjob.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 111.205.26.113#63499: query: onwzmlgpsfwzap.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 113.68.70.81#9947: query: kvajqdmxqxgzal.www.florasky.cn IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 95.193.118.38#13226: query: gnyjyrinovclsfqn.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 101.121.90.99#9047: query: wfglevwnqfwfkl.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 13.76.29.77#13797: query: ingrsrsdwvexkp.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 67.88.217.227#24213: query: edqjujahodyf.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
client 37.108.134.137#53089: query: qxojixixmpahyngx.www.ludashi789.com IN A + (MY SERVER IP)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to understand is that you're not the target of this attack. When recursion was enabled, nasty people found this in their network scans and your server was added to a list of attack nodes that were "willing" to assist them.

Even though the vulnerability has been patched, you are now in a database of vulnerable servers that has been distributed throughout at least one malware network. There is nothing you can do to change this: until someone decides to clean their list, these queries are just going to keep coming. Unless your pipe (or logging disk) is tiny, these queries shouldn't be having much impact on your server if they're being refused.

The only other thing I can really suggest is that you move this service to a different IP address, and replace this IP with a device that can comfortably drop all traffic on port 53.